# Recording Eclipse IDE screen? ( Windows 10 )

Tags: eclipse, windows-10, screen-recording

I tried to record with xbox Bar, but it only shows the main window.

When I test the game, create a new class, open painter, etc.. it doesn't show on the video

Comment: I use for quite some time [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/) (which is free and open source) to record [my Eclipse videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLnh_8hTD4yvnhXSttuewEKgKkmlIj_ND-) on Windows 10 which works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSDC Free Screen Recorder records everything that happens on screen: https://www.videosoftdev.com/free-video-capture